# What is wrong with my implementation for integration using Simpson's Rule

Tags: c

I was creating a C program for solving integrals using the Simpsons rule, I wrote it and it runs, but after giving the program the values it always returns me a value for the definite integral of 0.0000. I rechecked every line at it seems well, here's the code any help to this problem would be appreciated

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
float ad(int a, int b, int n)
{
    float f4, f2, z, v, q4=0, q2=0, d, m, fa, fb;
    int w=2, g=1, k=1, j=1;
    z=(b-a)/n;
    fa=6*pow(a,2)+16*pow(a,3);
    fb=6*pow(b,2)+16*pow(b,3);
    f4=6*pow(a+z*w,2)+16*pow(a+z*w,3);
    f2=6*pow(a+z*g,2)+16*pow(a+z*g,3);
    v=fa+fb;
    m=v*z;
    while(k<=n/2)
    {

        q4=q4+(z/3)*(4*f4);
        w=w+2; 
        k++;
    }
    while(j<=(n-2)/2)
    {

        q2=q2+(z/3)*(2*f2);
        g=g+2; 
        j++;
    }
    d=m+q4+q2;
    return d;
}
main()
{
    int x, y, l;
    float o;
    printf("Enter number x: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("Enter number y: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf("Enter an even number: ");
    scanf("%d", &l);
    if(l%2!=0)
    {
        printf("The number is odd!\n");
        return 1;

    }
    o=ad(x, y, l);
    printf("The aprox integral is es: %f\n", o);
    return 0;
}
```

It also gives me this two errors:

```
--------------------Configuration: mingw5 - CUI Debug, Builder Type: MinGW--------------------

Checking file dependency...
Compiling E:\anti simpson\ad.cpp...
[Warning] E:\anti simpson\ad.cpp:29: warning: converting to `int' from `float'
[Warning] E:\anti simpson\ad.cpp:50:2: warning: no newline at end of file
Linking...

Complete Make ad: 0 error(s), 2 warning(s)
Generated E:\anti simpson\ad.exe
```

Comment: I don't know about line #50, but line #29 is `return d;`, right? Have you attempted to solve these two errors?

Comment: At the very least, it appears that the `ad` function should return a float not an int. And this is basically what your first warning is reporting.

Comment: Add a newline after that final "}" and that other warning, which is stupid, will go away.

Comment: Jong the errors solved when I changed the function from int to float tanks to sharth and jams Black, but the program stills gives me an output of 0.000

Comment: Print out all relevant values while it's doing the iterations. That'll show you what's going on

Comment: James I did what you sujested and the only values that gives 0 are the v=fa+fb and m=v*z dont know why beacuse the previous values all gave numbers as I assigned 1 for a, 2 for b and 2 for n

Comment: Please add one or more examples showing your input, and the expected output. Inputting some random numbers (10,20,4) gave me an answer that is *not* 0: 572442.687500. Does that sound like a probably correct answer?

Comment: Jongware did you inputed them from the main() scanf's for the user input or assigned them in the function?

Comment: Jong I did inputed and yes you are right it gives me correct outputs but only for big numbers

Comment: ?? The program gave me the opportunity to input numbers, so I did just that. Additional note: `z=(b-a)/n`, for any `n > (b-a)` will always be 0, because this calculation is done with integers only. Presumably, you want this to be a float as well. Now I get '790145.81250' as an answer.

Comment: Please learn about `for()` loops it can save you a lot of scrolling around. Also: array indexing in C is zero based. Try to stick with it, or your progams will be polluted by +1 and -1 constants.

Comment: FYI: I changed the `z` line to `z=((float)b-a)/n;` and that changed *something*. But I still don't know if the answers I got are correct.

Comment: I tried with this http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=174a81e7a9ffb5aed0a790093981aaab

Comment: you are right, Jong how do I fix the n>(b-a) problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you declared your function as to return int, but you are returning a float,
the result is:
the float you are returning gets truncated, and you only get int.

I'm guessing all your integrals had a value between 0 and 1, so the function returned just 0

just change `int ad(int a, int b, int n)` to `float  ad(int a, int b, int n)`

**EDIT**: 
`z=(b-a)/n;` all a, b and n are ints, you won't get the fractional part in this division.
try `z=(b-a)/(n * 1.0);` just to cast one of the opreands to float so you get the fractional part as well

Comment: thanks already did, but stills returns 0.000 as value for the integral

Comment: Nice observation on the fact he was dividing by an int.

Answer (score 3):

One problem is this line:

```
int ad(int a, int b, int n)
```

Change it to:

```
float ad(int a, int b, int n)
```

This line and a similar one above it confuses me:

```
    q2=0;
    q2=q2+(z/3)*(2*f2);
```

Why set it to zero then set it to a value.  I expect it should be set to zero before the while loop.

Comment: ok so I changed the int of the funcion ad to float and defined the values of q2 and q4 to 0 in the float before the loops it still gives me 0.0000 as answer